# How to solve grails print method name conflict

Tags: grails, groovy

I have this code in grails

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
formatter.print(new DateTime()) // It's null
formatter.with{
   delegate.invokeMethod('print', new Datetime())
} // It's null
InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(formatter, 'print', new DateTime()) //It's null
```

I found where grails invokes the "invokePojoMethod" method, and the metaClass is ExpandoMetaClass, which contains the 'print' method

```
static Object invokePojoMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object arguments) {
   MetaClass metaClass = InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(object);
   return metaClass.invokeMethod(object, methodName, asArray(arguments));
}
```

How do I invoke the joda's DateTimeFormatter method 'print' directly and solve this name conflict?

Comment: Just to be on the same page here: you want to call joda's print here and assign the resulting string.  the comments with `// it's null` are just there to make the code shorter and your `print` calls, go for the groovy one and just print to stdout.  Is this correct?  Also what groovy/grails and joda version is this?  I use this is groovy 2.3.7 and grails 2.3 just fine.

Comment: @cfrick thx in advance. the commons with `// it's null` is the result of `print` call. Groovy works fine with code, but in the grails service, the `print` will invoke the `ExpandoMetaClass#print` method. My joda is 2.4, the grails is 2.4.3, thx very much